# ZF2 Capturing HeadStyle Helper

Tags: zend-framework2

I have used the following codes in my app.

```
<?php $this->headStyle()->captureStart() ?>
body {
    background-color: <?php echo $this->bgColor ?>;
}
<?php $this->headStyle()->captureEnd() ?>
```

I'm getting this error in my view script.

Fatal error: Call to a member function captureStart() on a non-object.

What's wrong?

Comment: Please include this line at the very top of your view script and dump the output: `<?php var_dump($this);exit; ?>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have followed. But, getting empty page. I have checked the view source.

Comment: How do you render the view script? Can you please paste the controller code if using MVC etc.?

Comment: I have posted that same code here. Expect your valuable response. Thanks.Note: I'm using ZF2.

Comment: What's your controller and routing setup like?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. I have used this code in layout.phtml